# Что можно сделать, чтобы часы правильно отображались в логе?

Tags: windows, cmd, консоль, bat, terminal

Добавил в планировщик скрипт, который должен выполняться с 4-х утра, каждые 10-ть минут.
Но он выполняется только с 10:00, что можно сделать, чтобы часы правильно отображались в имени файла?

```
chcp 1251

set VDATE=%date:~-10%
md D:\%VDATE%

set VTIME=%time:~0,-3%
set VTIME=%VTIME::=.%

openfiles /query /s 192.168.1.4 /fo csv /v > D:\%VDATE%\%VTIME%.txt
```

Comment: Добавить ведущий ноль. Т.е. безусловно добавить ноль и отрезать последние 8 символов. Т.е. `set VTIME=%time:~0,-3% && set VTIME=0%VTIME::=.% && set VTIME=%VTIME:~-8%`

Comment: Перевёл часы на 7-мь утра, но файл с логом всё ещё не создаётся.

Comment: А что при этом выводит `echo "G:\%VDATE%\%VTIME%.txt"`? вот именно так, с кавычками...

Comment: \13.09.2018\ 7.12.41.txt - пробел перед 7-й.

Comment: Косяк на косяке. Во-первых, пропало `G:` - уже странно. Во-вторых, вместо нуля затесался пробел - не менее странно. Отлаживайтесь - echo-йте результаты после каждой строки кода, причём именно вот так, в обрамлении, чтобы видеть пробелы.

Comment: О! Оказывается, для однозначных часов там пробел всё же выводится. Ну тогда `set VTIME=%time:~0,-3% && set VTIME=%VTIME::=.% && set VTIME=%VTIME: =0%`.

Comment: "D:\13.09.2018\:=.VTIME: =0.txt"

Comment: Эмм... у тебя что, вот так вот прям как у меня, в одну строку, в батче всё и записано? или в три строки?

Comment: chcp 1251

set VDATE=%date:~-10%

set VTIME=%time:~0,-3% && set VTIME=%VTIME::=.% && set VTIME=%VTIME: =0%

md D:\%VDATE%

openfiles /query /s 192.168.1.4 /fo csv /v > D:\%VDATE%\%VTIME%.txt
echo "D:\%VDATE%\%VTIME%.txt" > 1.txt

:: Ждём 1 минуту
timeout /t 60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот тест-батч и результат его работы.

```
time
echo %time%
REM chcp 1251
set VDATE=%date:~-10%
REM md G:\%VDATE%
set VTIME=%time:~0,-3%
set VTIME=%VTIME::=.%
set VTIME=%VTIME: =0%
echo "openfiles /query /s 192.168.1.4 /fo csv /v > G:\%VDATE%\%VTIME%.txt"
pause > nul
```

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Спасибо, файл создался. chcp 1251
set VDATE=%date:~-10%
md D:\%VDATE%
set VTIME=%time:~0,-3%
set VTIME=%VTIME::=.%
set VTIME=%VTIME: =0%
openfiles /query /s 192.168.1.4 /fo csv /v > D:\%VDATE%\%VTIME%.txt

Comment: *Способен ли cmd файл анализировать .txt файлы* Да. *Способен ли cmd файл анализировать .txt файлы* Фраза непонятна.

Comment: Отличие только в поле "ID"... как я могу понятнее объяснить?

Comment: `FOR /F` позволяет открыть текстовый файл, пропустить нужное количество строк, разобрать строку на токены по разделителю и проанализировать полученные токены. Но думаю, что по этому поводу надо создать новый вопрос...

Comment: Перебрать все файлы. В каждом искать в поле ID значение НЕ Администратор. Если не найдено - удалять.

Comment: Какая сложная команда.
У нас есть папка с сегодняшней датой "D:\14.09.2018"
Нужно удалить файлы "09.50.00.txt", "09.55.00.txt", "10.00.00.txt", "10.05.00.txt", "10.10.00.txt" если 11-я строка пустая.

Comment: Перебрать все файлы. В каждом пропустить первые 10 строк и проверить 11-ю на чего там надо. И нет в том ничего сложного...

Comment: Не понимаю, какую "матчасть" ты там читаешь, что такой бред получается... просто набери FOR /? в командной строке.

Comment: Для меня эта команда сложная мне нужно вникнуть, я ещё не понял как в ней сказать, что если строка пустая...

Comment: *я ещё не понял как в ней сказать, что если строка пустая...* `IF /?` там же, в командной строке.

Comment: Можете собрать команды?

Comment: Могу. Но здесь вопросы в вопросе не поощряются. Создайте новый.

Comment: Создал новый...